# property and synthesize : in this code, without "self"?

Tags: objective-c, properties, self

i have a simple question :
if we don't use here the dataController property in another class in the project, we don't really need to use the "@property" and synthesize and we could have just done a simple "=" operation with dataController = controller, like in the second chunk of code? :

```
DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];  
self.dataController = controller;  
[controller release];  
rootViewController.dataController = dataController;
```

Second one :

```
DataController *controller = [[DataController alloc] init];   
dataController = controller;
```

So if we don't need a property outside the class, we could just do it this way?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, if dataController is a retaining property.

If you are just using it once, there is not much to gain with a property. If you change its value often (i.e. assign a different DataController) then even a private property can make sense just to make the memory management easier.

Comment: +1  "a private property can make sense just to make the memory management easier."

Answer (score 2):

If dataController is not gonna be used in any other class then you don't need to synthesize it. Then Yes, you could just create it inside that class.

(Of course, if your dataController in your rootViewController also need a reference to it, then you need to handle that as well)

Comment: thanks Man of One Way for your answer, can i ask another question? if you let @property but don't write "synthesize", will it work? so can we use a "@property" without its synthesize? Thanks

Comment: "@property" is equivalent to creating function declarations.
"@synthesize" is equivalent to creating function definitions. Therefore it is of no use to use only "@property".

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second example works fine, provided dataController is declared as an iVar and not just a local variable to the method where it is used - but you probably are aware of that.

In both examples you of course need to release the stored value in the dealloc method.